# How to enable debug logging for GRE?

Tags: linux, debug, gre

How to enable debug logging for module ip_gre on linux 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no output generated in ip_gre.c, except for

```
printk(KERN_INFO "GRE over IPv4 tunneling driver\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "ipgre init: can't add protocol\n");
```

and

```
printk(KERN_INFO "ipgre close: can't remove protocol\n");
```

So I'm afraid you're out of luck..

Comment: I've looked a source code, there are no print at all. So, my question was a stupid, sorry.